# Do you have to check if an array element exists (not null string) in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If an associative array exists in Python3, is it a waste to check if an element of it exists rather than just using it?

Should you:

```
if 'name' in array and not array['name'].startswith('something'):
```

Or should you just:

```
if not array['name'].startswith('something'):
```

... And will Python3 handle it "for" you?

Comment: 2nd one will not work

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it was typo .... it will not work

Comment: No it won't. If 'name' is absent, the second snippet throws a KeyError. Just open an Python REPL and play around with dictionaries for a while. You will learn a whole lot more by tinkering.

Comment: You could easily answer your own question by putting this code into an interpreter (after creating your dictionary, of course) and trying to run it.

Comment: Try not to use a variable name `array`, since this is the name of a standard library module.  Be careful using that term with Python, use `list` or `dictionary` and only `array` when explicitly using a class of that name  (numpy also has arrays).

Comment: *not null string* - is a strange phrase to use in Python.  An empty string `""`  is a valid `str` object, it is not the lack of a value.  The nearest equivalent is a reference to the object `None`, but strictly speaking that is still a value (object).  Python does not act like Bash.

Answer (score 2):

You can do -

```
if not array.get('name', 'something').startswith('something'):
```

`get()` function returns the second value by default if the `key` ( `name` ) is not found.

So in above case , this would return `something` , if key is not found in the dictionary, and because of the `.startwith()` and the not , the complete  conditional expression would evaluate to False , as it would be doing in OP's first example .

Comment: Yes ? That is why I am using. 'something' as the second argument , so startswith would return True , which would become False , because of the not .

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on where does your `array` come from. Also on what can you do as a result of the check.

For example if it comes from the user, then yes, you definitely should check if `name` exists, so that you can respond with a better error message than `some big stacktrace.... KeyError: "name"`.

If it's an internal structure you created and it's not exposed for user modifications, or if it's exposed via API but the expectation is that nobody should touch it, then don't bother checking. If it's missing, then it's an internal exception the developers should see and fix.

Of course there may be a situation where you don't really care if it was provided or not, because you have a reasonable fallback. Then a default value like in Anand's answer is a good solution too. `array.get('name', some_default)`

Answer (score 0):

Python won't handle it for you. You'll have to do some work in both cases. Try to write code that makes sense to you later, because you'll write it once and read it (and maintain it) many times over.

You can do it two ways, pick the one that makes the most sense to you:

```
obj = array.get('name')
if obj and not obj.startswith('something'):
    pass
```

In your second option, you'll have to catch the exception:

```
try:
   if not array['name'].startswith('something'):
        pass
except KeyError:
   print('name does not exist in array')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do ...

```
 if not array.get('name',"").startswith('something')
```

If name exists then it returns array['name'] else it will return empty string .

Comment: Sure, if `'name'` exists in the dictionary. If it doesn't, it'll produce an error. That's why this snippet doesn't work.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 first you try and then try to upvote or downvote the answer .. see the above answer by anand ...

Comment: His answer is not the same as your answer. Your code, given a key not in the dictionary, will produce an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Ooohk @TigerhawkT3 u were right .. if i do array.get('name') .. it works fine and it will return none , but for array.get('name').some_function .. it wlll return errro ..

Comment: This will also return`true` in my opinion if `array['name']` is *not* in `array` :)

Comment: @elegent It will return none if 'name' not in array

Comment: No `get()` returns an empty string since you pass an `""`-string to `get()` :)

Comment: @elegent yes , it thought you are saying for array.get('name') ... :P